# how to access variables of one class from another in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hey guys i wanted to use the variables of lets say **class 1** in method **A()** in the **class2**
i have tried the following

```
class1 obj = new class1();
obj.A();
```

but its throwing an error saying cannot resolve symbol **A()**

Comment: and what happened ?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your variables to be public:

```
  public int variable1;
  public int variable2;

  Class1() {
      this.variable1 = 400;
      this.variable2 = 600;
  }

Class1 obj = new Class1();
obj.variable1;
```

Or just make them private and add getters:

```
  private int variable1;
  private int variable2;

  Class1() {
    this.variable1 = 400;
    this.variable2 = 600;
  }

  public int getVariable1() {
     return this.variable1;
  }

  public int getVariable2() {
     return this.variable2;
  }
```

then

```
Class1 obj = new Class1();
obj.getVariable1()
```

Comment: well the variable i needed to access out side of its parent class is declared in specific syntax and i don't know if i can declare it as an attribute

Comment: thanks @Gaston i was mistaken the variable i wanted to access is actually an object from another class i imported via a library

Answer (score 0):

you have to return that variable, like this:

```
class Class1 {
    public int A() {
        int a = 5 + 6;
        return a;
    }
}
```

You need to add this return statement: **return a;** at the end of A() function to return the value

Comment: thanks @Mureed i get now that the variable is not an actual variable it is an object to another method that i imported via a library